# Please add confirmation before placing flag/close vote from the Android App

Tags: feature-request, flags, vote-to-close, android-app

I have selected the wrong close reason on the Android app a few times already. You know how easy it is to tap on the wrong place of a touch screen.

What I request here is to slightly change the behavior of the flag/close reason list so that it either acts like the browser version (select then click on <kbd>Submit</kbd>) or prompt before submitting.

Comment: Totally agree, almost happened to me once, since then I don't use the app to flag/close stuff.